# Конфликт роутов laravel

Tags: laravel

Как правильно организовывать роутинг на laravel?
К примеру когда делаю вот так:

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'Controller@index')
```

Я без проблем открываю ссылки вида site.com/url
А что если мне понадобится конкретно задать роут к примеру

```
Route::get('/page', 'Page@index')
```

Как сделать так, что бы он не конфликтовал с первым роутом? Ведь по сути это одно и то же

Comment: поменять местами?

Answer (score 1):

Маршруты обрабатываются сверху вниз, а значит можно более общий маршрут поставить ниже.

```
Route::get('/page', 'Page@index');
Route::get('/{url}', 'Controller@index');
```

И всё будет работать.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй через switch:

```
Route::get('/{url}',function ($url){
    switch ($url){
        case 'post':
            function (Page $page){
                $page->index();
            }
            break;
        default:
            function(Controller $controller){
                $controller->index();
            }
    }
});
```